# Detect swipe from left side of the screen no matter what view is being displayed in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gesture

Right now I have this code:

```
    _swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiped)];

[_swipeRecognizer setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

[self.superview addGestureRecognizer:_swipeRecognizer];
```

and then this:

```
- (void)swiped {

    // find out where swipe started
    CGPoint loc = [_swipeRecognizer locationInView: self.superview];

    // if swipe was from side of screen and if sidebar is currently closed then open sidebar
    if(!_isOpen && loc.x <= 20)
        [self open];
}
```

however this only works if self.superview is the visible view. I want to make a sidebar like in the Facebook app, where you can swipe in from the left and detect that gesture no matter what view is on the screen.

Comment: So what view do you have that's always on the screen?

Comment: I have a UIScrollView that is always on the screen, except that when I try using the addGestureRecognizer: myUIScrollView then it does not work, I have also tried using "[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]" but neither worked. Why?

Comment: Take a look at this Ray Wenderlich tutorial which is on 'How to Create a Slide-Out Navigation Panel'. The code will probably answer your questions and then some. http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path

Comment: That tutorial uses pan gesture recognizer that is detected anywhere on the screen, not at the edges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the gesture recognizer to a view which is always on display. If you have other views in the hierarchy which also have gesture recognizers attached to them you will need to add a delegate to the gesture and implement `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` to return YES (otherwise the gestures will not operate at the same time).